# Firebase how to ValueEventListeners remove when other activity open in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, addeventlistener

I'm editing the question for more clarity

In my `Activity A`, I have have started my new `Activity B` for certain condition.
OnCreate of Activity A has the following

```
final DatabaseReference reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Example").child(userid);
        reff.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {`
                    navHeaderName.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue()).toString());
                    navHeaderId.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("member_ID").getValue()).toString());
                } else
                    reff.removeEventListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("RF-NavSet", databaseError.toString());
            }
        });
```

`

In the `fragment Af` is also si inflated in `Activity A`

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragment = new FragmentOfActiityA(); 
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.doc_fragment_container, fragment).commit();
```

In Fragment A also I have Firebase ValueEventListener

```
listener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                TextView text1 = view.findViewById(R.id.some_text1);
                TextView text2 = view.findViewById(R.id.some_text2);
                TextView text3 = view.findViewById(R.id.some_text3);

                text1.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child(userId).child("name").getValue()).toString());
                text2.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child(userId).child("specialisation").getValue()).toString());
                text3.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child(userId).child("member_ID").getValue()).toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("RF - SetProfile", databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        };

        reff.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
```

Here `reff` and `listener` are globally declared.

When I destroy Activity A, I want to remove listener in `Activity A` and `Fragment Af`.

How can I do that?

If I change any database value from some other `Activity X`, `Activity A` is automatically triggered due to these ValueEventListener which I dont want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the listener in your `onDestroy()` of activity `A`

```
mDatabaseRef.child(key).removeListener(mListener);
```

And your activity `A` in background when open activity `B` and if you want to remove listener then remove listener in `onPause()` and add listener in `onResume()`

Comment: @Jerin if you register listener in `onPause()` then need to remove in `onResume()`  means when other activity open then first `onPause()` call and unregister your `valueEventListener` so after change firebase value not triggers and if you register in `onCreate()' then remove in `onDestroy()` method

Comment: I defined the question more clearly, please go through. Im sorry but I cant connect your answer with my problem

Answer (score 1):

I have got the answer for the problem.
There one previous `Activity O` which I missed to removeEventListener which was secretly launching `Activity A`.

Took a while to understand that